# Input accepting char when it should be string?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am new to C++ and am making a simple text RPG, anyway, The scenario is I have a "welcome" screen with choices 1-3, and have a simple IF statement to check them, here:

```
int choice;
std::cout << "--> ";
std::cin  >> choice;

if(choice == 1) {
//..
```

That works fine, but if someone enters a letter as selection (instead of 1, 2 or 3) it'll become "-392493492"or something and crash the program. So I came up with:

```
char choice;
std::cout << "--> ";
std::cin  >> choice;

if(choice == 1) {
//..
```

This works kinda fine, but when I enter a number it seems to skip the IF statements completely.. Is the char "1" the same as the number 1?

I get a compiler error with this (ISO-CPP or something):

```
if(choice == "1")
```

So how on earth do I see if they entered 1-3 correctly!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `1` and `'1'` are not the same.

Look up your favorite ASCII table to know the integer value that represents the character "1" and you'll see it for yourself: `'1'` is mapped to `49`.

There is another issue with this code `""` denotes a C-string (`const char*`) whereas `''` denotes a single character.

Here is your code reworked:

```
char choice = 0;
if (cin >> choice)  // check success
{
  switch(choice) // choose
  {
  case '1': {  /**/ break; }
  case '2': {  /**/ break; }
  case '3': {  /**/ break; }
  default:
    cout << choice
         << " is not a valid choice, please press 1, 2 or 3 and Enter"
         << endl;
  }
}
```

I switched to switch because it's more natural than a chain of `else-if` for generic enumeration.

Comment: Why is `choice` a `char` in your code? `int` would make more sense.

Comment: Thanks alot! This inspires me to get a good C++ book, tutorials online don't show much important things like this.

Comment: @Konrad: I personally thinks it makes little difference and Jason had elected `char` in its last try so I just followed suit. The only issue is to be consistent either go for `char` and compare it to `char`s or go for `int` and compare it to `int`s.

Answer (score 3):

```
1 is an int
'1' is a char
"1" is a char array
```

I guess you want to compare with `'1'`.

Answer (score 3):

Choice doesn't become "-392493492" or something, it starts as that value (you didn't initialise it, so the initial value is unspecified) and is never set to anything else because the `>>` fails. You should check that such operators succeed, which is quite easy to do:

```
if (std::cin >> choice) {
    switch (choice) {
    case 1: // ...
    case 2: // ...
    case 2: // ...
    default: // report error
    }
}
```

Comment: The whole thing was within a while loop (to keep on checking until proper choice), I think I messed some of the break;'s up and it segfaulted the odd time, first time I got one, Maybe that integer was just some spit out error

Comment: No, the integer is essentially a random number. It's whatever number was in whatever memory cell happened to be allocated to that variable when you entered the function. Because the `>>` failed, the integer was left unmodified.

Answer (score 1):

`if(choice == '1')`

And to answer your question, the ascii valyue for 1 is not equal to 1, but is equal to 49:

```
'1' == 49
```

Answer (score 1):

A value in double quotes is interpreted as a string (of type `char*`, which is incompatible with a `char`), while in single quotes it is interpreted as a char:

```
if(choice == '1')
```

The integer representation of the char`'1'` is not 1, but 49 (in [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)). So you could also write

```
if(choice == 49)
```

Also, you should have an `else` branch to display an error message or something, and prevent the program from continuing in case an invalid input has been entered.

Answer (score 1):

choice is a char so you should use '1' to check. "1" represents a string with 1 character in it.